# What is the underscore prefix for python file name?

Tags: python, naming-conventions, prefix

In `cherryPy` for example, there are files like:

- `__init__.py`
- `_cptools.py`

How are they different? What does this mean?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`__...__` means reserved Python *name* (both in filenames and in other names). You shouldn't *invent* your own names using the double-underscore notation; and if you use existing, they have special functionality.

In this particular example, `__init__.py` defines the 'main' unit for a package; it also causes Python to treat the specific directory as a package. It is the unit that will be used when you call `import cherryPy` (and `cherryPy` is a directory). This is briefly explained in the [Modules tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Another example is the `__eq__` method which provides equality comparison for a class. You are allowed to call those methods directly (and you use them implicitly when you use the `==` operator, for example); however, newer Python versions may define more such methods and thus you shouldn't invent your own `__`-names because they might then collide. You can find quite a detailed list of such methods in [Data model](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization) docs.

`_...` is often used as 'internal' name. For example, modules starting with `_` shouldn't be used directly; similarly, methods with `_` are supposedly-private and so on. It's just a convention but you should respect it.

Comment: You are not expressly forbidden from inventing your own names. It is *discouraged* because the language might add more such names in the future, so the namespace is reserved. Using `__...__` names for your own projects is at your own risk.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: ok, replaced that with 'shouldn't'.

Answer (score 20):

These, and other, naming conventions are described in detail in [Style Guide for Python Code - Descriptive: Naming Styles](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles)

Briefly:

- `__double_leading_and_trailing_underscore__`: "magic" objects or attributes that live in user-controlled namespaces. E.g.`__init__`, `__import__` or `__file__`. Never invent such names; only use them as documented.
- `_single_leading_underscore`: weak "internal use" indicator. E.g. `from M import *` does not import objects whose name starts with an underscore.

Answer (score 8):

`__init__.py` is a special file that, when existing in a folder turns that folder into module. Upon importing the module, `__init__.py` gets executed. The other one is just a naming convention but I would guess this would say that you shouldn't import that file directly.

Take a look here: [6.4. Packages](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages) for an explanation of how to create modules.

General rule: If anything in Python is namend `__anything__` then it is something special and you should read about it before using it (e.g. magic functions).

Answer (score 3):

The current chosen answer already gave good explanation on the double-underscore notation for `__init__.py`.

And I believe there is no real need for `_cptools.py` notation *in a filename*. It is presumably an unnecessary extended usage of applying the "single leading underscore" rule from the [Style Guide for Python Code - Descriptive: Naming Styles](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles):

> - `_single_leading_underscore`: weak "internal use" indicator. E.g. `from M import *` does not import objects whose name starts with an underscore.

If anything, the said Style Guide actually is **against** using `_single_leading_underscore.py` in filename. Its [Package and Module Names section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) only mentions such usage when a module is implemented in C/C++.

In general, that `_single_leading_underscore` notation is typically observed in function names, method names and member variables, to differentiate them from other normal methods.

There is few need (if any at all), to use `_single_leading_underscore.py` on filename, because the developers are not **scrapers** , they are unlikely to salvage a file based on its filename. They would just follow a package's highest level of APIs (technically speaking, its exposed entities defined by `__all__`), therefore all the filenames are not even noticeable, let alone to be a factor, of whether a file (i.e. module) would be used.