# VS Code python doesn't autocomplete scipy.stats

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scipy, intellisense, scipy.stats

In `scipyt.stats` we have the variable `binom`
Somehow autocomplete in `vscode` doesn't seem to find it.
In pycharm the autocomplete works fine. Any pointers as though why it is so ?
Also just some sample code with binom as follows
`from scipy.stats import binom; binom.rvs(10,0.5,size=12)`.

[image: VS code Screenshot]

Comment: Make sure you selected the right python interpreter (F1 > Python: Select Interpreter). Also make sure you installed the Python extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the `__init__.py` file under `scipy.stats` package:

```
from .stats import *
from .distributions import *

from .morestats import *
from ._binomtest import binomtest
from ._binned_statistic import *
from .kde import gaussian_kde
from . import mstats
from . import qmc
from ._multivariate import *
from . import contingency
from .contingency import chi2_contingency
from ._bootstrap import bootstrap
from ._entropy import *
from ._hypotests import *
from ._rvs_sampling import rvs_ratio_uniforms, NumericalInverseHermite
from ._page_trend_test import page_trend_test
from ._mannwhitneyu import mannwhitneyu

__all__ = [s for s in dir() if not s.startswith("_")]  # Remove dunders.

from scipy._lib._testutils import PytestTester

test = PytestTester(__name__)
del PytestTester
```

It does not contain: `from ._discrete_distns import binom`. So the Pylance will not prompt it in the suggestion list.

You can import it through: `from scipy.stats._discrete_distns import binom` like `bwdm` suggested above.

Comment: This looks like a flaw in Pylance.  For historical reasons, the import of the name `binom` into the `scipy.stats` namespace goes through a couple levels of indirection (`__init__.py` imports from `distributions.py`, and `distributions.py` imports from `_discrete_distns.py`).  The end result, however, is that `binom` is a public name in the `scipy.stats` namespace.  The leading underscore in `_discrete_distns.py` is there precisely to *avoid* having users import directly from that module; being private, it is potentially subject to change in future versions of SciPy.

Comment: To be more definitive: in general, you should *not* import from `scipy.stats._discrete_distns`.  The contents of that  private module could be changed, or the module itself could be renamed or removed at any point in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [binom](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.7.1/scipy/stats/_discrete_distns.py) is defined in the submodule `scipy/stats/_discrete_distns`, which is imported by the main module in [`scipy/stats/__init__`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.7.1/scipy/stats/__init__.py). I believe that variable doesn't get autocomplete because it's defined in an internal module of `scipy.stats` (`_discrete_distns` has the [underscore prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192207/what-is-the-underscore-prefix-for-python-file-name)), i.e. VS Code treats it as "private" in this case.

I tried a few extensions like IntelliCode and Pylance, but it still doesn't autocomplete `binom` from `scipy/stats`. The only way I managed to get it to autocomplete was by importing `scipy/stats/_discrete_distns` directly.