# VScode does not find module norm in scipy stats

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scipy, pyright

The  `scipy.stats`  have a module called `norm` but VScode does not seem to find it.

[image].

I am aware of this very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69001787/vs-code-python-doesnt-autocomplete-scipy-stats), but I am no able to solve my problem based on the answer givin there.

Scipy is installed in a Conda environment.

Using VScode 1.61.2 and Conda 4.10.3.

Comment: This will not affect the execution of your script in any way.  The `norm` module is "built" when `scipy` is instantiated.  It's not in a separate file.

Comment: So it is actually impossible to autocomplete this since it do not exist befor run-time?

Comment: I'm wouldn't say it's impossible, but certainly "more trouble than it's worth".

Comment: Thank you for the help. I see now that I needs to study the Scipy module a little deeper in order how this "building on instantiation" works.

Comment: If this is the same issue as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69001787/vs-code-python-doesnt-autocomplete-scipy-stats, then this is apparently a flaw in the pylance plugin for VSCode (see my comment in the linked question).

Comment: I also have the same problem in Neovim using coc-pyright, but as far as I have understood Pylance uses Pyright also?

Comment: Can you import it like this `from scipy.stats._continuous_distns import norm`?

Comment: That worked!! Why is VsCode Python autocompleter (PyRight) picking up norm when imported like that?